# Regexp to selectively match email

Tags: regex, email

I need a regexp that will matches an email that follows these rules:

It can be

```
anyemail@anydomain.tld
```

OR

```
noreply@mydomain.com
```

however it can not be any other email from mydomain.com

So far I tried using something like this:

```
 (\w+@[^mydomain]\w+.com)|(noreply@mydomain.com)
```

however it doesnt seem to work as expected - it fails for every domain starting with `m`. Like `anyemail@myotherdomain.com` would fail and it should not. I am using PHP regexp btw.

Comment: You need a negative lookahead, not a negated character class. Use `\w+@(?!mydomain\.com)\w+\.com|noreply@mydomain\.com` or something like this. Try [`\w+@(?!mydomain\.com)\w+\.\w+|noreply@mydomain\.com`](https://regex101.com/r/oK8rO0/1).

Comment: Yes Mr Righteous, it works great. 2 questions: 1. How do I accept a comment as an answer cause I want to do things `the right way`, 2. would it be so difficult to post this answer into a question I asked previously when I had no idea about `negative lookahead` or `negated character class` instead of down-voting it and deleting it?

Comment: When I am not sure what you need, I post a comment. If it works for you, I can explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, `[^mydomain]` is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches 1 character that is not `m`, `y`, `d`, `o`, `a`, `i`, `n`. To actually *restrict* some generic pattern, you need to use a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (here, a lookahead), i.e. `(?!mydomain\.com)`.

Note that to match any TLD, you can use `\w+` instead of hardcoding it as `com`.

Also, if you want to match a literal `.` symbol with a regex, you should either escape it (`\.`) or place inside a character class `[.]`.

So, use

```
\w+@(?!mydomain\.com)\w+\.\w+|noreply@mydomain\.com
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK8rO0/1)